# Potential energy stored by an elastic circular loop on deformation to an ellipse

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential-energy, spring, elasticity, continuum-mechanics

This question is related to an origami circular loop that I built. This structure is elastic and I intend to find the elastic potential energy stored by it when I deform it to an ellipse.

My actual intention is to launch something using this, which I'm able to do. I'd like to find the height an object would reach, and I think this is possible if I'm able to determine the potential energy stored by such structure on deformation(The object **can** be considered as a pure elastic boy for the sake of simplicity. but I'd appreciate if you don't take it as a pure elastic body).

Comment: There are too many unknowns to calculate the potential energy.  Your best approach will be to measure it: use a weight to do the deformation, and the potential energy in your loop will equal the chance of gravitional potential energy of the weight.